# HTTP "DELETE" request hangs on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed to AWS for first time, and experienced a very strange behavior. I use AngularJS and there is a function that performs $http service call with DELETE method specified.

```
var fn = function () {
    $http({ method: "DELETE", url: "/active/route/"})
...
```

and when I perform it, request hangs for a while and get refused.

I've changed fn to

```
function () {
    $http({ method: "POST", url: "/active/route/delete"})
 ...
```

And it worked just fine.

I want to know if beanstalk has specific policy about some HTTP methods or what was causing this behavior?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this issue? I am noticing the same behavior using jquery to send AJAX requests

Comment: In the end we figured out that AWS load balancer just rejects all 'DELETE' methods, so you won't be able to use this method in case you're deploying to elastic beanstalk. No workarounds were found, so we just switched to 'POST'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has been fairly inactive for a while but I figured out what was happening in my case and thought I would post it here for anyone else who needs it. Basically http DELETE methods do not play nice if you are sending a request that contains a request body. Pure RESTful services should be employing the URI to pass object ids back and form, rather than form data or in the request body. When the data is passed via request body some web servers will read that as a POST method, which can wreak havoc on your API.

In my case I was passing the object id both in the URI and, as a side effect of my architecture, in the request body. This works perfectly ok in all cases except DELETE. To fix the issue I simply removed the unnecessary request body and viola!

Hope this helps someone.

See this post for more detail:

http://www.spenceruresk.com/2011/11/http-delete-requests-that-include-a-body/